# Append to registry without expanding variables

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'll just start off by saying that I'm by no means an expert in C++, so any pointers/tips are greatly appreciated.
I'm having some difficulties reading and writing from registry, while keeping variables, i.e. not expanding them.
I'm trying to append my executable path to the PATH environment variable (permanently), but I'm running into all sorts of problems.
I have a long PATH variable that makes it impossible to edit without using a program or regedit, so I opted to create an "OldPath" variable with my current PATH variable, and change my PATH variable to %OldPath%. This has worked great, but now when I try to write to it with C++, %OldPath% gets expanded into the old path variable and as a result, the variable gets truncated.

I tried first with normal strings, but I ended up with what looked like Chinese symbols in my PATH variable, so I changed it to wstring. Now I get normal strings, but the string gets truncated at 1172 characters.

My desired end result is that PATH is set to `%OldPath;<current_path>`

**get_path_env()**

```
inline std::wstring get_path_env()
{
    wchar_t* buf = nullptr;
    size_t sz = 0;
    if (_wdupenv_s(&buf, &sz, L"PATH") == 0 && buf != nullptr)
    {
        std::wstring path_env = buf;
        free(buf);
        return path_env;
    }
    return L"";
}
```

**set_permanent_environment_variable()**

```
inline bool set_permanent_environment_variable()
{
    const std::wstring path_env = get_path_env();
    if (path_env == L"")
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << path_env;
    if (path_env.back() != ';')
    {
        wss << L';';
    }
    wss << std::filesystem::current_path().wstring() << L'\0';
    const std::wstring temp_data = wss.str();
    HKEY h_key;
    const auto key_path = TEXT(R"(System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment)");
    if (const auto l_open_status = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key_path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &h_key); l_open_status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        const auto data = temp_data.c_str();
        const DWORD data_size = static_cast<DWORD>(lstrlenW(data) + 1);
        // ReSharper disable once CppCStyleCast
        const auto l_set_status = RegSetValueExW(h_key, L"PATH", 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, data_size);
        RegCloseKey(h_key);
        if (l_set_status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>("Environment"), SMTO_BLOCK, 100, nullptr);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In other words, I want to find the equivalent of the following in C#:

```
var assemblyPath = Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location).FullName;
var pathVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $"{pathVariable};{assemblyPath}", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

EDIT: I actually haven't tested if that code expands the value or not, but I want to do as the C# code states and if possible, not expand the variables in the path variable.

Comment: Maybe you want to get the old value of the registry key, not the value of the PATH environment variable which has already been expanded?

Comment: Yes, `PATH=%OldPath%`, so I want to get that and append to it so it becomes `PATH=%OldPath%;new_value`. I want this to be portable, so that if people use variables in their path, I want those to stay there

Comment: _wdupenv_s does not return "%OldPath%" though. It returns the actual path, after OldPath has been expanded, *because that's what's in the environment variable PATH*. Being expanded before it goes in the environment variable was the whole point, remember! You need to get it from somewhere before it's been expanded, e.g. the registry.

Comment: ok, but how do I go about doing that programmatically then?

Comment: you want to ask how to get the path value from the registry? even though your program already sets the path value to the registry?

Comment: No I want to know how to get the value from the registry without expanding the %variables% in it. My program does not set that, it's been set beforehand. I'm trying to read the value and append to it - keeping all variables in it, i.e. %OldPath% in this example.

Comment: Getting the value from the registry already doesn't expand the %variables% in it. Your program does not get the value from the registry.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well you are getting the value from the environment, changing that, and putting it into the registry, when you are trying to get the value from the registry, change it, and put it into the registry. I am not sure how else to explain it to you. The environment is not the registry.

Comment: The TV script says "The year is <current year> and the president is <name of current president>". I want to add some more text. So I watched the person read it out loud on TV and he said "The year is 2009 and the president is Barack Obama." So I wrote a new script that said "The year is 2009 and the president is Barack Obama and the most popular sport is <most popular sport>." But they it's 2018 and the president is Trump and that script is wrong! How do I update a TV script without expanding the <variables>?

Comment: I got it now, using RegQueryValueExW. Thank you for your help. Could you post an answer, so I can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the PATH setting in the registry. So one would expect that you would get the current PATH setting from the registry, change it, and set the new PATH setting in the registry.

But you are not getting the PATH setting from the registry. You are getting the PATH variable from the environment instead. Why is that? The environment is controlled by the setting in the registry, but it's *not* that setting. In particular, you noticed that the environment variables set in the registry get expanded before they actually go into the environment.

It's like changing the wallpaper by taking a screenshot of the desktop, changing the screenshot, then setting it as the wallpaper, then asking how to remove the icons from the wallpaper.

The solution is to simply get the current unexpanded PATH setting from the registry instead of the expanded one from the environment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "environment" and "registry" are lowercase words. Also while I was a bit unclear, I think it is probably important to distinguish between the environment variable configuration stored in the registry and the actual environment variables.